# How to split a links got by API and display the images in React JS

Tags: reactjs, image, api, split

This is the API response:

```
"placePhotos": "https://i.ibb.co/RvZk2yH/butakovka.jpg,https://i.ibb.co/RNyqScq/butakovka.jpg"
```

I can't split the links split(',').

2 question: 
Then if split the links, how to display images? using loop? maybe... can I save the splitted link to array and display the images using array.map?

```
<CardMedia
    component="img"
    alt={placeDescription.placeName}
    height="140"
    image={placeDescription.placePhotos}
    title={placeDescription.placeName}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split your data, you should you `.split(',')`, you will receive an array containing 2 URLs. If you want to render multi-component from an array, you should use `.map()`. Try this:

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <div>
    ...
    {
      placeDescription.placePhotos.split(',').map((url, index) => 
        <CardMedia
          key={index}
          ...
          image={url}
          ...
        />
    }
    ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It displays: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: @MyrzabekAldiyar Can you show me the result of ```console.log(placeDescription)```. I think that ```placeDescription.placePhotos``` may be undefined

Comment: I have already solved the problem. Thank you. The solve is below in the answers

Answer (score 1):

You can split `placePhotos` which will create an array which you can then map over

```
placePhotos
  .split(',')
  .map(photo => <img src={photo} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` is **unsafe**. I would recommend using RegExp here :

```js
const regexp = /https?:\/\/.*?\.(?:png|jpg)/g;

response.placePhotos.match(regexp).map(url => (
  <CardMedia
    key={placeDescription.placeName}
    component="img"
    alt={placeDescription.placeName}
    height="140"
    image={url}
    title={placeDescription.placeName}
  />
));
```

For your information, you should avoid using index as a component's key when possible : https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 0):

```
{
                                placeDescription && placeDescription.placePhotos && placeDescription.placePhotos.split(',').map((url, index) =>
                                    <CardMedia
                                        component="img"
                                        alt={placeDescription.placeName}
                                        height="250"
                                        image={url}
                                        title={placeDescription.placeName}
                                    />
                                )
                            }
```